# Adding to a Kafka topic exactly once

Tags: apache-kafka

Since 0.11, Kafka Streams offers exactly-once guarantees, but their definition of "end" in end-to-end seems to be "a Kafka topic".

For real-time applications, the first "end" however is generally not a Kafka topic, but some kind of application that outputs data - perhaps going through multiple tiers and networks - to a Kafka topic.

So does Kafka offer something to add to a topic exactly-once, in the face of  network failures and application crashes and restarts? Or do I have to use Kafka's at-least-once semantics and deduplicate that topic with potential duplicates into another exactly-once topic, by means of some unique identifier?

**Edit** Due to popular demand, here's a specific use case. I have a client C that creates messages and sends them to a server S, which uses a `KafkaProducer` to add those messages to Kafka topic T.

How can I guarantee, in the face of

- crashes of C, S, and members of the Kafka cluster
- temporary network problems

that all messages that C creates end up in T, exactly once (and - per partition - in the correct order)?

I would of course make C resend all messages for which it did not get an ack from S -> at-least-once. But to make it exactly once, the messages that C sends would need to contain some kind of ID, so that deduplication can be performed. That, I don't know how I can do it with Kafka.

Comment: Using idempotent producer and transaction should help to write data to a Kafka topic exactly-once -- you will still need to write additional custom code to avoid duplicates. The question is quite open ended and hard to answer in detail though.

Comment: if you can give more thorough details, we can try to answer the question. Right now,its too vague.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax In what way is a question about the most basic - from a Kafka user's perspective - operation, namely "adding an item to a topic", "open ended"? How could I narrow it down?

Comment: "So does Kafka offer something to add to a topic exactly-once" -> as mentioned above: yes but maybe not a complete solution without custom code. Look into idempotent producer and transactions. Not sure if you are familiar with both -- if yes, narrow it down to why those features don't provide what you need.

Comment: @MatthiasJ.Sax I added a use case to the question - hope that's specific enough.

Answer (score 1):

Kafka's exactly-once feature, in particular the "idempotent producer" can help you with server crashes and network issues.

You can enable idempotency via `Producer` config `enable.idempotence=true` that you pass in as any other config. This ensures that every message is written exactly once and in the correct ordered if the server crashes or if there are any network issues.

Kafka's exactly-once feature, does not provide support if the producer crashes. For this case, you would need to write manual code, to figure out which messages got appended to the topic successfully before the crash (by using a consumer) and resume sending where you left off. As an alternative, you can still deduplicate consumer side as you mentioned already.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at kafka's Log compaction feature. It will deduplicate messages for you provided u have unique key for all the duplicate messages.

https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction

Update:

Log compaction is not very reliable however you can change some settings to work as expected.

The more efficient way is to use kafka streams. You can achieve this using KTables.

Comment: Log compaction is something completely different. It frees up space, but does not prevent Kafka consumers from receiving the same item twice.

Comment: There is no way it can be avoided ... Say the duplicate recods are produced at time t , t+5min and t+10min.. there is no way we can know that the record is duplicate at time t. Additionally compaction is not just for freeing up space it makes sure you have the latest state of your record.